# QGIS and BSB files for 3D Printing

Tags: qgis, raster, 3d, mac

I am new to GIS. I'm a sailor and 3D printing enthusiast.

What I want is to  print a 3D representation of my sailing area.

I've acquired the raster files for my navigation charts and they consists of .kap and .bsb which is what is required for QGIS.

I have the raster files in KAP and BSB format. However when I open the KAP files in QGIS I see only 6 or 7 layers. When I open a NOAA file in the same format, I see there are over 30 layers.

I also installed the DEMto3D plugin to generate the STL files to send to the printer.

I'm not sure that the data set contains enough details to allow me to do what I what. I end up getting a file with no depth.

Running QGIS 2.18.23 on Mac

Comment: Do you have any bathymetry (depth) data?

Comment: Yes, I have the raster files in KAP and BSB format. However when I open the KAP files in qGIS I see only 6 or 7 layers. When I open a NOAA file in the same format, I see there are over 30 layers.

Sorry if I don't use the right language, as I mentioned, I have no experience in GIS.

Comment: According to http://libbsb.sourceforge.net/bsb_file_format.html, a .bsb file provides the information to link together multiple .kap files. Each .kap file is a separate layer or page in a nautical chart. It sounds like this file format is flexible, and each set can have a different number of layers.

Comment: I tried to enhance the difference using "MyMap@1"*100. I can see the change in the slicing software after going through DEMto3D but I still believe my original data is not good.

Comment: Additional question: how can I confirm that my KAP/BDB files have the correct depth in them? Is there a plugin or tool to view the min/mac elevations in the file?