# Plotting 3D data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d

Has anyone used QGIS to plot 3D data (temperatures profiles at different depths at sea)?

Comment: What have you researched/tried?

Comment: I haven't see much discussion of using QGIS for 3D printing on this site. For example, [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293504/qgis-and-bsb-files-for-3d-printing) recent question about using QGIS for 3D printing went unanswered.

Comment: There's a dedicated 3D stackexchange site, although the number of questions there with the GIS tag is similarly low. But it did link me back here to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228827/generating-stl-3d-file-from-raster-aster-gdem-data) which might provide some tips for you.